# Laravel Mix one sass to multiple css

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

When trying this:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app_blue.css', {
        data: '$theme-bg-primary: #1450d9;'
    })
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/app_red.css', {
        data: '$theme-bg-primary: #ba0000;'
    });
```

the output from npm is `should not contain the item '[...]/app.scss' twice.`

How to ouput 2 distincts css from one source as app.scss ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of injecting your data into the mix call, you need to create a stub scss file for each theme you are creating.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app_red.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app_blue.scss', 'public/css')
```

Where those scss files include the base `app.scss` and overrides that you are injecting with your `data` value.

Comment: After some reflection on my side, I ended up with same conclusion than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a different variable values for both css files. You have to call .sass twice but to optimize it further i would suggest you to use variables.

e.g.

```
const cssSourceDir = 'resources/sass/';
const cssPublicDir = 'public/css/';
const commonSassFile = `${cssSourceDir}/app.scss`;
```

duplication can be removed like this

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass(commonSassFile, cssPublicDir+'/app_blue.css', {
    data: '$theme-bg-primary: #1450d9;'
})
.sass(commonSassFile, cssPublicDir+'/app_red.css', {
    data: '$theme-bg-primary: #ba0000;'
});
```